# Wrapping multiple texts around a circle and distribute them evenly

Tags: inkscape

I wish to *wrap* text onto a circle.

I know I could select first the circle, then the text, but I wish to put multiple text on the same circle, and align them evenly, to reach something similar like this:

[image]

If I select multiple texts *and* the circle, `Text/Put on Path` doesn't do anything.

Tried putting them one-by-one to the circle, and then do a *Circular Distribution*, but it gives very awkward results.

How shall I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To get text on a path you need to select one text box (not multiple) and the circle, then do *Text > Put on Path*.
2. Once you have the text on a path you can select the circle twice, and rotate it using the rotate handles

[image]

3. Select the text box twice to see the rotation handles appear
4. Move the centre of rotation to the centre of the circle.
5. In the Transform panel, select the Rotate tab, and put in the angle you want to rotate. In this example I did 360/7, which is equal to 51.429
6. Duplicate using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and hit Apply in the Transform panel.  Repeat until finished
7. Finally edit the text. If you want, set the circle stroke to none

An example showing steps 3 to 7

[image]

Comment: Ah, do you know what was my fault? Texts were *left-adjusted* (by default), and they always ended up starting at 0 degree after put onto path, and I couldn't set them the correct angle. Also, I tried to rotate the text itself by pulling, and that way it's not snapping to anything.

Comment: Ah, do you have any idea on how could I deal with these labels when letter-spacing is set to `-2`? https://imgur.com/a/AvPjtDe It seems I lose the precise alignment

Comment: Changing the letter spacing is a little tricky. I assume your text is already set to centre align before you attached it to the path.  Select and highlight all characters except the last, then change the letter spacing. [see example](https://imgur.com/zxKYGcO).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method is to prepare all the text boxes, draw a circle (or an ellipse) and use <kbd>Align and Distribute</kbd> tool selecting the <kbd>Circular</kbd> tab.

[image: Circular alignment]

By clicking <kbd>Arrange</kbd>, the work is done:

[image: Text aligned]

Comment: Yes, but this is a bit wrong: see 220, it should be placed to top (at 12).

Comment: The first object created is aligned at the 0° angle, so you can simply group the objects, rotate 90° the group counterclockwise with Ctrl-I, ungroup. In my example I started with the text box "70", which is properly aligned.